# db2_connect to as400 with php and wamp server

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange, wampserver

I have been trying to connect to a **ibm db2** database but it seems impposible. The **as400** is in a different server than the one running php.

Everytime I do a `db2_connect` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function db2_connect()
```

How can I make this function work?

**Tip**:  I've already tried with `odbc` and it was a lost of time, but I'm open to suggestions on that path as well.

[EDIT]

I finally changed to java... it was impossible with php...

Comment: You can install Zend Server, which comes with php_ibm_db2.dll precompiled on windows. But even so I wasn't able to connect to the AS400 from PHP. From Java (e.g. DbVisualizer and jt400.jar) it was very easy.

Comment: Um... I know this is late, but it seems like you just didn't have the DB2 extension installed/enabled for PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file and make sure it has the DB2 extension enabled.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: 
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/09/db2_udb_part2/

Deals with:
  Installing the PHP DB2 extension, 
  Creating a connection, 
  Obtaining a result set

Also gives as an alternative the PDO option.

But as for DB2 on the AS400, am not sure if something still needs to be installed on the
AS400 for this to work?
Anyway, have used the ODBC Client Access with no problems at all. What difficulty did you run into?